# Change from one layout view to another and going back?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

want to make an Android app that starts with a *main* layout and when you push a button (called *stateButton*) that is in this layout the layout changes to a *main2* layout containing another button (called *boton2*), and when you push this one you get back to the first main.

I want to do this in the same activity without creating or starting another one.

Here I show you part of the code:

```
public class NuevoshActivity extends Activity
implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {
    private Button stateButton;
    private Button boton2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        this.stateButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.boton);
        this.boton2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.boton2);      
        stateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        boton2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==stateButton) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);             
        }
        else if(v==boton2) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }
}
```

The mains only have some images, text views and the buttons.

But I've some troubles. Can't it just be as simple as that or what am I missing or what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `boton2` button will be NULL because the definition of the button is in `main2.xml`.
The only views you will be able to find are the views which are defined in `main.xml`.

Answer (score 4):

When you use findViewById, you are actually trying to find a view inside the layout you specified by the setContentView. So using setContentView again and again might bring problems when you are trying to check for buttons.

Instead of using a setContentView, I would add the 2 layouts for the screen as child's for a view-flipper which only shows one child at a time. And you can specify the index of which child to show. The benefit of using a view flipper is that you can easily specify a 'in' and 'out' animation for the view if you need an animation when you switch between views. This is a lot cleaner method then recalling setContentView again and again.

Answer (score 2):

The `FrameLayout` handles this wonderfully...    Use this with the `<include...` contstruct to load multiple other layouts, then you can switch back and forth between them by using `setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);` and `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` on the individual layouts.

For example:

Main XML including two other layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frameLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include android:id="@+id/buildinvoice_step1_layout" layout="@layout/buildinvoice_step1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></include>
    <include android:id="@+id/buildinvoice_step2_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" layout="@layout/buildinvoice_step2" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></include>
</FrameLayout>
```

Code to switch between layouts:

```
findViewById(R.id.buildinvoice_step1_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.buildinvoice_step2_layout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

You will also need to set the visibility of the individual layouts when the activity starts (or in XML) otherwise you will see them both - one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!! All the info was usefull to understand a lot of things and as C0deAttack commented I've got troubles with the button on the main2. What I've done is to set View.VISIBLE and View.GONE to the TextViews and Buttons that I wanted in each layout. Thank you very much.